# Examples of failed leftist movements without support today

Tags: political-history, historiography, north-america

By support I mean popular support, whether in polls or any means of trying to gauge the views of the average citizen.

It seems like almost every major historical movement spearheaded by the left eventually succeeded, ranging from expansion of voting rights in various ways (to non landholders, African Americans, all races, women), abolition of slavery, reduction of working hours, expansion of protest freedoms, and libel loosening.

This begs the question of what role the conservative party serves. One important one I realized quickly is that perhaps they rein in new influences, and stop anything too radical from being passed. With that in mind, what are some radical ideas from the past that never took off, and wouldn't even have support today either?

I can think of eugenics and lobotomies, but the former wasn't entirely leftist and the latter was more medical than political.

Comment: Involuntary eugenic sterilization was a very popular leftist position.

Comment: "the past" - that's rather broad I think...

Answer (score 1):

The [Communist Party of the United States of America](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communist_Party_USA#Best_results_in_major_races).

It was formed in 1919, gained some support & prominence in the 1930s, began declining during World War II and never recovered.